# How to center a fontawesome icon inside a div element

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a div with `width: 180px;` and `height: 180px;`.
How can I center a fontawesome icon horizontally and vertically inside the container?
Note: i may also add text below the icon

```
<div style="width:180px; height:180px; float:left;">
  <i class="fa fa-search fa-4x"></i>
</div>
```

should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: text-align: center; line-height 180px;

Comment: @Hanze see update 1 in my answer.

Comment: updated my answere, took me a lil bit but this should work fine for you centering everything to 100% :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
#search{
    background: gray;
    width:180px; 
    height:180px; 
    float:left; 
    line-height: 180px;     
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#search > p {
    margin-top: -155px;
}
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/kasperFranz/h91p8w4e/3/ (using icon instead of fa in the example, but shouldn't affect the result.)

Comment: How is it affecting the size of the icon?, there is nothing in this there are chaning the size of the icon)

Comment: sry kasper, this is not 100% :) if you delete the text, the icon is not 100% centered. Actually it has to move lil bit more up or down, depending if text is shown or not.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
.centered{
position:relative;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}

.container{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

On mobile.

Comment: Helpful, but I had to put position:relative on .container and position:absolute on .centered

Answer (score 2):

Asuming to my comment, here is a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t2aocd80/)**

Without setting `relative` or `absolute`

html

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <!--i class="fa fa-search fa-4x">test</i-->
        <i class="icon-search icon-4x"></i><br />
        <span class="myText">Search</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.myDiv{
    width:         180px; 
    height:        180px; 
    float:         left;
    background:    #ccc;
    text-align:    center;
    display:       table;
}

.content_wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.myText{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:   20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably too late here, but it's a common question, so here's a simple working idea, the interesting side of it is that it adapts to the container size:

```
span{
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
    background:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block" style="height: 300px;">

    <div class="centered">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
        <p>p1</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="block" style="height: 200px;">

    <div class="centered">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
        <p>p2</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="block" style="height: 600px;">

    <div class="centered">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
        <p>p3</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/y7c3ykbm/)

> Update 1:
>   [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/0mt6uhm4/1/)

Comment: Pretty sure that's not what he is asking for ;)

Comment: @Kasper Franz ``;)`` does not know exactly what he wants to do.My answer is correct.Thank you for your curiosity.**:))**

Comment: i agree with @KasperFranz

Comment: What he wants is: [Absolute Horizontal And Vertical Centering In CSS](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) or [Centering a Div Both Horizontally And Vertically](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/).
I gave him a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late and you probably already figured this out.

I was able to achieve what you were looking for by wrapping the icon and text in a div then adding padding to that.

See the attached pen.

http://codepen.io/ForTheJim/pen/YPxveR

```html
<p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="YPxveR" data-default-tab="result" data-user="ForTheJim" class='codepen'>See the Pen <a href='http://codepen.io/ForTheJim/pen/YPxveR/'>Centering Icon Question</a> by Jim (<a href='http://codepen.io/ForTheJim'>@ForTheJim</a>) on <a href='http://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short way just add `display: grid; place-items: center;` to your div and your ready to go.

like this:

```
<div style="width:180px; height:180px; display: grid; place-items: center;">
  <i class="las la-user-circle"></i>
</div>
```